# How to fix 'Automation Error' in vba when querying worksheets

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to join three tables to show inventory by location for similar Items associated by "Key".

So to do that, I am joining my product list, DS, to SM which is my master list with associated products on KEY, which is an index of different product information. Finally I need to pull each one of those item's inventory information by location.

It is throwing an "Automation error" from VBA when it is trying to establish the recordset. This works when I dont have the second join in my SQL string (attaching INV table).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim strFile
Dim strCon
Dim strSQL
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim I
Dim SQL

strSQL = "SELECT s1.KEY, s1.Item, Loc, QOH, Total_Ship_To_WIP, Tot_Opn+pick_Units, Reserve " _
& "FROM ([SM$] AS s1 " _
& "RIGHT JOIN [DS$] AS s2 ON s1.[KEY] = s2.[KEY]) " _
& "LEFT JOIN [INV$] AS s3 ON s2.[Item] = s3.[Full_Style]"

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

rs.Open strSQL, cn 'error

For I = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a10").Offset(0, I).Value = rs.Fields(I).Name
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a11").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding ```cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient```
and i would suggest addign .close for cn and rs

Comment: Thanks, but the error I had was found in my table data, I had to rename Tot_Opn+pick_Units to Tot_Opn_pick_Units